# How do you create an echoing mock using Moq?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am creating a mock for my `ITransformer` interface.

```
public interface ITransformer
{
    String Transform( String input );
}
```

I can create a mock that returns an given string based on a specific input:

```
var mock = new Mock<ITransformer>();
mock.Setup(s => s.Transform("foo")).Returns("bar");
```

What I would like to do is create a mock with a `Transform()` method that echoes whatever is passed to it. How would I go about doing this? Is it even possible?

I realise my question might be subverting the way that Moq and mocks in general are supposed to work because I'm not specifying a fixed expectation.

I also know that I could easily create my own class to do this, but I was hoping to find a generic approach that I could use in similar circumstances without having to define a new class each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var mock = new Mock<ITransformer>();
mock.Setup(t => t.Transform(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns((String s) => s);
```

This should echo back whatever was supplied to the method.

Comment: Been wondering about that It.IsAny, just never had a chance to look it up.

Answer (score 4):

```
var mock = new Mock<ITransformer>();
m.Setup(i => i.Transform(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns<string>((string s) => { return s;});
```

Comment: Your edit makes no sense - `string` is an alias for `System.String`